# Overriding SetThreadExecutionState

Tags: windows, winapi, screen, power-management

I am not sure if this belongs on serverfault or superuser.

I would like to override SetThreadExecutionState(ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED) to be a no-op. How is this accomplished?

Is there some registry setting that can be altered instead of API hooking?

> Blocking ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED will prevent apps from keeping the monitor powered on. I have an application (likely the antivirus) that is preventing some monitors from entering power-save and I think this function is the culprit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you get too far down that road, have you confirmed that it *is* the antivirus? If you're on Windows Vista or Windows 7, use POWERCFG.EXE /REQUESTS (as administrator) to check.

Also, [this thread](http://uclue.com/?xq=3587), which links to [this document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/E/7/7E7662CF-CBEA-470B-A97E-CE7CE0D98DC2/AvailabilityRequests.docx), says to use POWERCFG.EXE /REQUESTSOVERRIDE to veto SetThreadExecutionState.